# preg_replace with slash in the end

Tags: php, preg-replace

got this code

```
<?php

$string = "list page.php?cpage=1, list page.php?cpage=2, list page.php?page=3 thats all";
$string = preg_replace("/\?cpage=[0-9]/", "/", $string);
echo $string;
//result 
//list page.php/, list page.php/, list page.php/ thats all
//what i want 
//list page.php/1/, list page.php/2/, list page.php/3/ thats all
?>
```

any one can help?

demo
https://3v4l.org/LEvph

Comment: Do you have a question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capture the value between () and project it back via $1:

```
$string = "list page.php?cpage=1, list page.php?cpage=2, list page.php?page=3 thats all";
$string = preg_replace("/\?c?page=([0-9]{1,})/", "/$1/", $string);
echo $string;
```

`([0-9]{1,})` means one or more digits.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
  $string = "list page.php?cpage=1, list page.php?cpage=2, list page.php?page=3 thats all";
  $string = preg_replace("/\?c?page=([0-9]+)/", "/$1/", $string);
  echo $string;
?>
```

The expression uses the [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) `([0-9]+)` to match any integer and capture its value. Then, it uses `/$1/` as a replacement. Notice `$1` is a backreference to the value captured by the group.

For example:

```
preg_replace("/\?c?page=([0-9]+)/", "/$1/", "page.php?cpage=3");
```

captures `"3"` in group 1 and `/$1/` is evaluated in the replacement as `"/3/"`.